# How to get my current culling mode, DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I need to know my current culling mode. I would to like to get D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC filled by some function. Is it possible? How? Or i only can set states but not get them?

I dodn't set it, but i want to know the default settings.

Comment: If you've set it, how can you not know what it is? You also have [RSGetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476476(v=vs.85).aspx) if necessary, from which you can get the description.

Comment: @ Roger Rowland, i dodn't set it, but i want to know the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get the cull mode by [ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) unless you set it first, or you will get null pointer.(I test this on my code)

Let's dig it a bit more,

in DirectX 9, the default cull mode is [D3DCULL_CCW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), we when say culling, we always refer to back face culling, so what is back face? a front face is one in which vertices are defined in clockwise order.Any face that is not a front face is a back face. Direct3D does not always render back faces; therefore, back faces are said to be culled.

In DirectX 10, whether a face is front or back depends on you, there is filed called FrontCounterClockwise in [D3D10_RASTERIZER_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and it's default value is FALSE, and the deault cull mode is D3D10_CULL_BACK, same as DirectX 9.

In DirectX 11, the [D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has same members as that in DirectX 10, but unfortunately, the document didn't specify the default value of cull mode.

I guess DirectX 11 will also use D3D11_CULL_BACK by default. When you defined a triangle in clockwise order and render it, everything works fine, but when you change it to counter-close wise, you will see nothing.

**EDIT:**
See the remark section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it give the default values. thanks MooseBoys for point this out.

Comment: See the Remarks section of the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198(v=vs.85).aspx) for the default rasterizer values.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to look at the [ID3D11DeviceContext::RSGetState method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You should then be able to get the description from the ID3D11RasterizerState output argument.